# What tools to use for C/C++ and CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, code-analysis, static-analysis, jenkins

FYI: If there is a better place/site (Programmer SE, for eg), feel free to move/close this question and let me know.

I am running Jenkins as our CI server, and we program mostly in C and C++ (with a little perl scripting here and there). Anyway, I have the following tools that I use to create metrics with for every build:

- NSIQ (LOC and Complexity)
- CPPCheck (for static analysis)
- gcovr (for coverage)
- CPD (for DRY checking)
- StatCVS (for developer information and tracking - just for funsies, not really useful from a CI perspective)

Are there any others that you know of that we could use, preferably with a Jenkins plugin or some form of XML/HTML output? I tried CCCC, but it was not as proficient with our code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently attended a talk about [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). I do not yet personally use it, but we are actually setting it up at work and I plan to use it at home for my hobby projects.

I had not heard of it until recently, but I am extremely impressed with everything that I have seen with it so far.

The biggest negative is that it maintains its own pages, although Jenkins (and Hudson) should be able to launch it to start it.

Comment: Are you using/plan to use Sonar with C/C++? Everything I've read about it seems to suggest a Java/Maven combination.

Comment: I personally am using it with Java and preparing to use it for C#, but we are not using Maven. This is a tool that should work with C++: [MetriC++](http://forge.isotrol.org/wiki/6). We do not yet use Sonar, so I am not all-that versed in its use, but from the demonstration that I have seen I expect great things. Check out the former link, and here is [their documentation](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-has-become-a-multi-languages-platform/#more-4021) mentioning future, official C support from them.

Comment: I was reading their documentation, and it seems they already have a C plugin, which is great. However, even to use Sonar light (only static analysis), you need a minimal pom.xml. Ugh. Thanks though, will look into it further.